# How can one change the titlebar text?

Tags: scripting

Can I change the content of the blender window's title bar?

I want to change, the user understands the software content

[image]

Comment: This isn't really a question about Blender. The answer will probably depend on your operating system and relates more to programming or operating system operation than Blender itself.

Comment: For the record you asked this [exact same question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/74647/2217) back in Feb of this year. It was auto deleted "(RemoveDeadQuestions)", so what makes you think asking it again will be any different?

Comment: Since your on windows, try renaming the exe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find where this is set in the [sourcecode](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/), change it, then [compile it](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender).
A quick search finds it in [line 368 of `wm_window.c`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/windowmanager/intern/wm_window.c;989080c4f644836ebbe085e5dddc812edc876ee7$368):

[image]

---

*Note: Currently [questions dealing with the source are off-topic](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/225/599). In light of [recent debate about expanding our scope](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2216/599), I wrote this answer as a sort of proof of concept.*