# Change Blender logo

Tags: source-code

I realize that questions about the source code are considered off topic, but in light of [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/78019/12805) answer, I figured I'd ask anyway in case there's someone out there that does know the answer.

I've been looking through the Blender source code and it looks like there are many places where the Blender logo is stored. I found a couple neat tools to be able to change the icons by updating the blender_icons.svg file stored in release/datafiles, but is there any single place where I could change the Blender logo such that it shows up on the task bar as a different image?

Thanks!
Anson

[image]

Comment: Hi :). Isn't this related more to your OS than Blender?

Comment: Yeah, I'm mostly asking about the Blender source code.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this commit is the one that updated the logos during the change with Blender 2.80:

https://github.com/blender/blender/commit/3b8ae2c08f5c72742a12dd91eaae58c8973dbdbc

Updating these files should also update the logo when Blender is built.